# asp.net OpenXML insert data to cell

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, openxml

I've been following this guide https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/cc861607.aspx to insert a string to a cell in an excel file. The example is really confusing, and even when i copy/paste it doesn't work. I'm looking for a very simple example to insert a a value into a cell like:

```
spredSheet.InsertCell("A", 1, string value)
```

I could really use a simple code example showing me how to insert data into a cell using OpenXML in asp.net.

I tried the code from this post [Using OpenXML to insert a datatable into excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072456/using-openxml-to-insert-a-datatable-into-excel), but it creates a broken excel file.
This is how my code look without the helper functions from the link

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.
            Create(Server.MapPath("/data.xls"), SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookpart = myDoc.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            //add column names to the first row  
            Row header = new Row();
            header.RowIndex = (UInt32)1;
            SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();


                Cell headerCell = createTextCell(1, 1, text);
                header.AppendChild(headerCell);

            sheetData.AppendChild(header);
            // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);
        }
```

Comment: you just want to set the cell data, correct ?

Comment: Yes, i just want to set the cell data

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505628/c-write-xlsx-using-openxmlwriter-and-open-xml-sdk

Comment: I used this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072456/using-openxml-to-insert-a-datatable-into-excel and I like the answer in that thread, modify after my needs. Works just fine!

Comment: @Dreamweaver that example doesn't work. I get a object is not set to an instance of an object on `WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.Last();`

Comment: @WeeklyDad i tried your example, but i can't seem to get it to work. It creates a broken excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSDN example is using `SpreadsheetDocument.Open` which opens an *existing* file but you are creating a brand new file with `SpreadsheetDocument.Create`. When you create a brand new file there are certain elements you must create in order for the file to be valid. The elements you are missing are the `Sheets` and `Sheet` elements.

`Sheets` are stored separately from the `SheetData` so you need to create a `Sheet` inside a `Sheets` and then associate the `Sheets` with the `WorksheetPart`.

This can be done like so:

```
Sheets sheets = myDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
sheets.AppendChild(new Sheet()
{
    Id = myDoc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(myDoc.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First()),
    SheetId = 1,
    Name = "Sheet1"
});
```

So your full code listing would be something like:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.
       Create(Server.MapPath("/data.xls"), SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookpart = myDoc.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    //add column names to the first row  
    Row header = new Row();
    header.RowIndex = (UInt32)1;
    SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();

    Cell headerCell = createTextCell(1, 1, text);
    header.AppendChild(headerCell);

    sheetData.AppendChild(header);
    // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

    //this is the part that was missing from your code
    Sheets sheets = myDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
    sheets.AppendChild(new Sheet()
    {
        Id = myDoc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(myDoc.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First()),
        SheetId = 1,
        Name = "Sheet1"
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @petelids. Your sample led me the right way